# How can I implement a Javascript/HTML Playground with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to implement a simple Javascript Playground like jsFiddle and was wondering on the best way to achieve this. From the way jsfiddle works, it creates an iframe with the submitted HTML/Javascript code. The source of the iframe comes from a dynamically created page from the jsfiddle server.

I was wondering if it would be possible to do this with client side javascript code only. I have tried this but does not work (custom code is not executed and do not know if jquery is loaded in the iframe):

```
$iframe = $(document.createElement("iframe"))

$html = $iframe.contents().find("html")

//HTML code
$html.children("body").append($(htmlcode))

//Javascript code (first jquery and then custom code)
$script = $(document.createElement("script"))
$script.attr("src","jquery.js")
$html.children("head").append($script)

$script = $(document.createElement("script"))
$script.html(javascriptcode)
$html.children("head").append($script)

$iframe.appendTo($("body"));
```

Comment: As written, what I mean is that it seems the custom code is not running nor the jquery code seems to be loaded. I guess the browser do not allow for this but would like an explanation on why

Comment: And what I mean is that you didn't narrow down the problem at all with any debugging...

Comment: I firebug'd the iframe created but the script element do not appear. If I create a script which do not calls any external lib, something like alert("hello"), it works. Again, if you point me to a debugging method, I am more than glad to do it. Thanks for the help

Comment: Let me guess, you're a php dev.

Comment: Were you running low on semicolons when you wrote that? Did you have to sell them all for dollar signs?

Comment: user886931 is saying that there shouldn't be `$` in front of variables, and you should put `;` after every line.

Comment: I use $ in front of variables only if they are Jquery objects. I do not use it in front of other type of variable. Got it for the ;

Comment: Instead of changing the DOM of the Iframe, you must write its content with the function document.write. Then it works.

Comment: I found the answer. Basically, you need to write the output with a document.write function. Then it works :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to be that complex.
Just open a new window (or an `iframe`) and put your HTML inside it.

Demo: [***`http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/uSrU6/4`***](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/uSrU6/4) (**UPDATED**)

Comment: Thanks Derek. However something like this in the textarea would not work:  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script>
$("#hello").click(function(){alert("hello")})
</script>
<div id="hello" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:red"></div>

Comment: @seb, you will have to put it in `head`.

Comment: Done that as well with same result as you can see above.

Comment: @Seb, Then I guess you will have to use `PHP`.

Answer (score 0):

also I'm not completely sure I understand what exactly are you trying to do. I think you have a mistake in the code you posted:

1. You are trying to append the script to `$html.children('head')` while `$html` is not the `$iframe` itself but the contents.. I think `contents()` doesn't return a DOM element so the rest after that isn't valid anyway. **edit** - now I see in the comments that regular js does work for you so this probably ain't the problem
2. I vaguely remember there is an issue with cross site scripting when calling js libs from another domain in an iframe. Not sure about that

EDIT: Found it: [here](http://www.codecouch.com/2008/10/cross-site-scripting-xss-using-iframes/) maybe this is the issue. There is also a solution here